# Add a value to a checkbox on Magento admin and set it to checked

Tags: php, magento

I've added a checkbox to a new admin panel using an installer, but I can't get it to add a value or check it once it's saved. Here's the installer script:

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'feature_activated', array(
    'group'             => 'New Feature Settings',
    'type'              => 'int',
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Feature activated',
    'input'             => 'checkbox',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => '',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '',
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'apply_to'          => '',
    'is_configurable'   => true,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true, 
    'sort_order'        => 15
));
```

When the admin panel renders, it generates this:

```
<input id="feature_activated" name="product[feature_activated]" value class="" type="checkbox">
```

If I check the box and save, it doesn't save the value (probably because there is no value), and obviously, it doesn't show as checked the next time I load the page. I've had a lot of trouble finding documentation on this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that magento has checkbox attribute. If this is not a problem for you you can use yes/no select field.

```
$installer->addAttribute('catalog_product', 'feature_activated', array(
    'group'             => 'New Feature Settings'
    'type'              => 'int',
    'backend'           => '',
    'frontend'          => '',
    'label'             => 'Feature activated',
    'input'             => 'select',
    'class'             => '',
    'source'            => 'eav/entity_attribute_source_boolean',
    'global'            => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
    'visible'           => true,
    'required'          => false,
    'user_defined'      => true,
    'default'           => '0',
    'searchable'        => false,
    'filterable'        => false,
    'comparable'        => false,
    'visible_on_front'  => false,
    'unique'            => false,
    'apply_to'          => '',
    'is_configurable'   => true,
    'used_in_product_listing' => true, 
    'sort_order'        => 15  
));
```